# Yii2 Call to a member function field() on a non-object

Tags: model, controller, field, yii2

I wanna show all usernames in User tables of Database. It show

```
Call to a member function field() on a non-object
```

in the line    `<?= $form->field($model, 'id')->dropDownList(`

When end user click a button to add User into Project, a pop-up will appeared
This my code in file popup:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\modules\admin\models\User;
?>
<select name="from" id="multiselect" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
  <?= $form->field($model, 'id')->dropDownList(
       ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->asArray()->indexBy('id')->where(['status'=>1])->all(),'id','username',
       ['prompt'=>Yii::t('app', 'Select User'), 'data-placeholder'=>Yii::t('app', 'Select User'), 'class' => 'form-control select2me', 'style'=>'width: 100%'] ));
  ?>
</select>
```

Beside, this popup in Project Assignment Controller, not in Project Controller.

My ProjectAssignmentController:

```
public function actionPopup() {
        $model = new ProjectAssignment();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->renderPartial('popup', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `dropDownList()` creates dropdown list, no need of `select`. try removing it.

Comment: i think you should add this line if not added: `$form = ActiveForm::begin();`

Comment: This is my full popup code: [link](http://pastebin.com/Wp0Jf1Y1)
But when I add `$form=ActiveForm::begin();` It's appeared error `Division by zero`

Comment: have you tried below answer?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but it's appeared an error `Division by zero`. This is the first time I meet this error

Comment: where you get this error?

Comment: in this line `'action' => ['controller/action'],` 
I replace this to `'action' => ['project-assignment/popup'],`

Comment: where is your add user button?

Comment: try combining yii2 modal and bootstrap modal using js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89117/discussion-between-trexanhvn-and-insane-skulll).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is the popup the complete code? then you haven't added a `$form`

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
'method' => 'post',
'action' => ['controller/action'],
]);
... your fields code ...
ActiveForm::end();
```

the dropDownList renders the select html code itself, so you should have to add it with plain html.

Comment: no. code in popup is too long, so I paste it in http://pastebin.com/Wp0Jf1Y1
with your edit.
and it's appeared an error `Division by zero`

Comment: two things are wrong

use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm; // missing otherwise ActviveForm::end() wouldn't work.

and your action wasn't in ' ' but you can leave it blank to post to current action.

see http://pastebin.com/X4KuvuiL

from the pastebin code i couldn't see why you getting a division by zero. could be someting in your used model?

Comment: I fixed like your said and it's ok now.
Thanks you very much